# Bull.js is not getting the exported function in NestJS with webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, nestjs, bull.js

My NestJS application compiles my Typescript worker

```js
async function bootstrap(job: Job, done: DoneCallback) {
  //...
}
export default bootstrap;
```

into a js file with following line:

```js
exports["default"] = bootstrap;
```

But Bull.js is throwing the following error:

```bash
/usr/src/app/node_modules/bull/lib/job.js:516
          reject(new Error(failedReason));
                 ^
Error: origProcessor.apply is not a function
```

It only works if I manually add into the compiled js file:

```js
module.exports = bootstrap;
```

Does anyone know how to properly config webpack to get it? I'd like to keep using webpack since all projects are using it.

Additional info:

- bull version: 4.10.4;
- webpack version: 5.76.3;
- nestjs version: 9.3.12;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out by deeply reading the docs from webpack and debugging master.js in bull package.

Just add commonjs as library target in webpack config:

```js
module.exports = {
output: {
  //filename: ...
  //path: ...
  library: {
    type: 'commonjs-module',
  },
 }
}
```

The compiled js file will have this line:

```js
module.exports = __webpack_exports__;
```